# jqueryui datepicker with hidden input

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I got a button and a hidden input.

I want the datepicker opens below the button I click it.
And the selected date is inserted in the hidden input.

I don't want to create a new button (using datepicker options), and I don't wanna show the input.

```
<button type="button" class="btn" id="date_button">Select Date...</button>

<input type="hidden" name="date" id="date_field" />

<script>
    $('#date_button').datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        onSelect: function( dateText ) {
            $('#date_field').val( dateText );
            $('#date_button').text( dateText );
        }
    })
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

I did this by doing a .show().focus().hide() - works perfectly though it's a bit unclean:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').datepicker();
        $('#mybutton').click(function() {
        $('input').show().focus().hide();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JKLBn/

Comment: Does not work in IE with newer jQuery versions. (Probably because IE sets focus asynchronously)

Answer (score 1):

This is a little hacky, but it seems to work okay:

1. Attach the datepicker to the `input` instead of the button.
2. Reposition the datepicker to be underneath the button when it opens.

```
var $button = $("#date_button"),
    left = $button.offset().left,
    top = $button.offset().top + $button.height();

$('#date_field').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $('#date_field').val(dateText);
        $button.text(dateText);
    },
    beforeShow: function (event, ui) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            ui.dpDiv.css({ left: left, top: top });      
        }, 5);               
    }
});

$button.on("click", function() {
    $("#date_field").datepicker("show");
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/StUsH/

Comment: @J.Ghyllebert I've updated the jsfiddle to a version that works. There appears to be an issue in jsfiddle with jQuery 1.9.1 and jQueryUI 1.9.2, the datepicker chokes on `$.browser.msie`.

Comment: Instead of using a hidden input, use a text input and hide it with CSS. Initializing the datepicker on a hidden input will cause an error on positioning.

Answer (score 0):

I did it different way.
I have hidden normal text input by the button with style:

```
style="outline: none; color:white; margin-top:-20px; border:none;"
```

so it doesn't appear on the page. It is focusable and it just works fine.